# Bootstrap Starter Template Not Displaying the Same as the Source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn how to use Bootstrap with a rails application and don't understand a difference between the Bootstrap [Starter Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) and what I see when I load  my rails app.

I copy-paste the source code of the Starter Template directly into my root view of my application. But when I run rails s, and go to localhost, the div with h1 "Bootstrap Starter Template" is displayed to the left and **underneath** navbar.

I've googled reasons for this, and I've seen that there's a solution to add padding to the body class.

**What I don't understand:** 
 why do I need to add the padding solution to my copy-pasted view when the same source code displays perfectly fine on the bootstrap examples page

I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm using gem bootstrap-sass version 3.3.5

Comment: Did you add the whole starter template, DOCTYPE and all, into a view? Are you using a layout?

Comment: Did you also copy the linked [starter-template.css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css) file? (It contains `padding` and `text-align` rules.)

Comment: @Tiago I did not add the starter-template.css file. A couple questsions: where did you find the starter-template.css file? and where would I add this css file into my rails application? under assets>stylesheets>application.css or under assets>stylesheets>welcome.css.scss (the welcome page is the one I'm adding the starter template to)

Comment: Look at the starter template HTML source code. The CSS file is linked in the `head`. If your _application.css_ has the `require_tree` directive, it will auto-include any other (s)css files in the _stylesheets_ folder. So you can just drop a _starter-template.css_ file in that folder, and it will work.